# when i am trying to add plugin cordova-app connect not working

Tags: android, cordova

**cordova plugin add cordova-appconnect –searchpath AppConnectCordovaPlugin_Android**

not working when i am trying to add plugin

UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): CordovaError: Failed to fetch plugin cordova-appconnect via registry.

Answer (score 0):

This error is very obvious.
There is no plugin named as **cordova-appconnect**.

Please make sure which cordova plugin you want to add.

Comment: Hi i want to implement SSO(Single sign on) to android application for Mobileiron. In ios Mobileiron provides a  plugin called Apache Cordova Appconnect but in android creating a custom code is required.Can you please help me out in which i can implement it.Can you suggest a blog or example in which i can look and implement it.Thanks in advance